# regex "condition"

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regex, which would return false in PHP in case that string contains backslash and doesn't continue with 3 digits.
For example:

```
something\something   -> false
\                     -> false
something\            -> false
something\45something -> false
something\222aa\a     -> false
something\000         -> true
\784something         -> true
\784                  -> true
something             -> true
something\222aa\111   -> true
```

I found out that regex `(\\\d{3})+` works fine for backslash and 3 digits after.

I don't know how to get it together with that `something -> true` (I get false on this).

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. What's wrong here?

Comment: What's something? a static string?

Comment: Yes, it is static string

Comment: So you need something like `(?m)^something$|\\\d{3}`? Demo https://regex101.com/r/8HmyHc/1

Comment: What about the string `something\123something\12` or `some\123thing\123`? Would you expect them to be `true` or `false`? Or is this something that can not happen?

Comment: The 1. one is false, the 2. is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/ETBJ4L/2) to match invalid inputs (containing a slash that's followed by less than 3 digits):

```
\\\d{0,2}([^\d]|$)
```

Hence, if the input matches the regex return `false`, otherwise return `true`.

***Edit***: Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte for the fix.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You're correct, my bad. Fixed it

Comment: It almost works, it does't in this case: `something\45`

Comment: I found out that it works on that page you sent, but it doesn't work in PHP, not even in preg_match online ((https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html))

Comment: After a long time I found out that I must use `$re = '/\\\\\d{0,2}([^\d]|$)/';
$str = 'asd\\';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);`, not `preg_match`

Answer (score 2):

The best I could manage is a multiline regex which check if the line either contains a slash followed by 3 digits, or contains any character other than a slash or newline

EDIT:
In light of the question modification

```
^([^\n\\]|\\\d{3})*$
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `something\111something\asd`. I will edit question.

Comment: Now it works only for `something`, I am trying it here (https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html) , because there it works same as in PHP

Comment: Try putting this into preg_match_all /^([^\n\\]|\\\d{3})*$/m

Comment: I did it like `$res = preg_match_all("/^(\[^\n\]|\\\d{3})*$/m",$argument[1]);
    if($res != 0) 
    {
     exit(21);
    }`
and it doesn't wrok